# How do I link back to a paginated and sorted list if that list is implemented using AJAX. I'm using Rails 3.2

Tags: ajax, sorting, ruby-on-rails-3.2, pagination, back

I have a list of items that are paginated using will_paginate and this works great. I finally implemented AJAX following instructions from a [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax) and it works like a charm. However, now, when I navigate to an item's page, and then click the "back" link, the page and sorting are lost.

For example, in a list of Books, if I sort them via title and go to the second page, then click on a Book, that works fine. Then when I click "Back", I am taken back to the first page of the list without the sorting. I understand this is because the URL is no longer updated with the AJAX call.

How do I maintain pagination and sorting for back links with AJAX in my rails app?

This is the code I use to implement the AJAX:

results.js.erb:

```
$("#search_results").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "layouts/search_results_list").html_safe %>");
```

pagination.js:

```
$(function() {
  $("#search_results").on("click", ".sort a, .pagination a", function() {
    $.getScript(this.href);
    return false;
  });
});
```

From the Book page, I simply use:

```
request.referer
```

to go back to the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of searching and not being able to find an appropriate solution, it turns out [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/246-ajax-history-state?view=asciicast) had the answer all along in a different post. Adding these lines to pagination.js did the trick:

```
history.pushState(null, "", this.href);
$(window).bind("popstate", function () {
    $.getScript(location.href);
});
```

This changes the URL with every AJAX request. Much simpler than other solutions I was contemplating.